# Finding a Linear Operator with Given Characteristic and Minimal Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

Let $T\in\mathcal{L}({\mathbb{C}^4})$ be the linear operator that we wish to determine (i.e., $T: \mathbb{C}^4 \to \mathbb{C}^4$). As $T$ is defined in a complex vector space, $\mathbb{C}^4$ will admit a decomposition in terms of the null spaces defining the general eigenvectors of $T$.

$$
\mathbb{C}^4 = \text{null}(T-\lambda_1)^{d_1} \hspace{5pt}\oplus \hspace{5pt}... \hspace{5pt}\oplus \hspace{5pt} \text{null}(T-\lambda_k)^{d_k} 
$$

where $d_1,...,d_k$ count the multiplicities of each eigenvalue and $d_1 + ... + d_k = 4$. The characteristic polynomial $p_c(z) : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is then defined as
$$p_c(z) = (z-\lambda_1)^{d_1} ... (z-\lambda_k)^{d_k}$$

We can define the minimal polynomial as follows. The space $\mathcal{L} (\mathbb{C}^4)$ is parameterized by matrices possessing a one in a single location and zeros elsewhere. For example, one such basis vector will be the matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Consequently, $\text{dim}(\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^4)) = \text{dim}(\mathbb{C}^4)^2 = 16$. The list of operators given by
$$
(I, T, T^2, ..., T^{n^2})
$$
will posses $n+1$ elements and cannot be linear independent. Selecting $m$ to be the smallest such index that the list is linearly independent, we find that $\exists a_0, ..., a_{m-1} \in \mathbb{C}$ s.t.

$$
a_0 I + a_1 T + ... + a_{m-1} T^{m-1} + T^{m} = 0
$$

which shall yield for us a minimal polynomial $p_m (z) : 
\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ of the form

$$
p_m(z) = a_0 + a_1 z + ... + a_{m-1} z^{m-1} + z^m
$$

(In fact the Cayley-Hamilton theorem improves this bound by restricting the total number of terms to $\text{dim}(V) = 4$.

By the fundamental theorem of algebra, we may factor
$$
p_c(z) = (z - \lambda_1)^{d_1} ... (z-\lambda_k)^{d_k}
$$
$$
p_m(z) = (z- \lambda_1') ... (z-\lambda_4')
$$

As every root of the minimal polynomial $p_m(z)$ is inherently an eigenvalue every $\lambda'$ may be identified with some lambda neglecting multiplicity.

**Question:** Given $p_c(z)$ and $p_m(z)$ in factored form, how may we determine a linear operator $T$ on $\mathbb{C}^4$ whose characteristic polynomial is $p_c(z)$ and whose minimal polynomial is $p_m(z)$?

**Remark:** I have noticed (from dumb luck) that a matrix of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & c_1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & c_2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & c_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for undetermined coefficients $c_1, ..., c_3$ will work for minimal polynomials of degree less than three.

Comment: the minimal polynomial is not always in the form you have written. For example, there may be a matrix whose characteristic polynomial is $x^4$ and minimal polynomial $x^2$. In other words, eigenvalues may have also multiplicities in the minimal polynomial (called geometric multiplicity)

Comment: Also, the matrix in the remark has characteristic polynomial equal to $x(x^3-c_3x^2 - c_2x - c_1)$ so for example, a minimal polynomial like $(x-1)^2$ cannot be represented by it

Comment: About your remark 1: you have re-discovered "by pure luck" an important tool of linear algebra: the concept of ["companion matrix"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping that there was already a theory behind my guess. I wish that it was included in conventional linear algebra books. Incidentally, do you have any recommendations for further reading? Thanks again.